# onAuthStateChanged called too many times and force rebuild of top widget

Tags: flutter, stream, firebase-authentication

I use flutter with firebase auth, and I try to use streamBuilder with the **onAuthStateChanged** from Firebase Auth.

If user is signedIn I return the homeScreen and in others cases the signInScreen.
Everything is working great, but when I add a print('') in the streambuilder (just before the if for example) I can see that my streamBuilder is called too many times, for example when I push a new screen, when I pop a screen ...etc.. even if there is no data (just an empty Container()) in these screens. At least onAuthStateChanged is called twice by any of my action (push, pop...) with connection.waiting state and connection.active.

Because of that my homeScreen is rebuilt each time, that mean my whole application is rebuilt each time.

The decision code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: userBloc.currentUser.onStateChange(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return HomeScreen();
          } else {
            return SignInScreen();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

My main goal is to force streamBuilder to rebuild widget only if **snapshot.hasData** change, and not when **onAuthStateChanged** receive something not useful and doesn't need to rebuild my whole app.

Comment: did you solve it? I'm having exactly the same problem

Comment: No, it still work like this but rebuild each time something happened with inAuthStateChanged.